# Some doubts about Spring bean inizialitazion and destruction

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

in this period I am studying Spring Framework.

Now I am studying about the spring Bean life cycle and in particular about the inizialitazion ad destruction of a bean, reading this tutorial:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_life_cycle.htm

I have implement the example proposed in the previous article but I have a doubt about this argument.

In the example I have only two classes: **HelloWorld.java** and **MainApp.java**

In the **HelloWorld.java** class I have the two method for the bean inizialitazion: **init()** (called by the framework after the creation of the bean) and for the bean cleanup: **destroy()* (called by the framework before the bean destruction at the end of my application)

Ok, this is clear, these two method are automatically called by the framework in two specific moment of the bean lifecycle because I have delcared it for this bean inside the application context xml file by the **init-method** and **destroy-method** attributes:

```
<bean id="helloWorld" 
    class="org.andrea.myexample.myInitDestroyExample.HelloWorld"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
</bean>
```

This is appear clear for me.

The thing that I have some problem to understand is related to the beginning of the previous article, infact it show that to have inizialization method, my bean have to implement the **InitializingBean** interface and the code of it's method called: **afterPropertiesSet()**

And for execute the bean cleanup (before that this is deledet) my bean have to implement the **DisposableBean** interface and the code of it's method: **destroy()**

Ok...so...why in the article first show that my bean have to implement these interfaces and then, in the example, don't do this thing but simply declare the presence of init and destroy method in the XML configuration and implement it inside my class that don't implement no interfaces?

Tnx

Answer (score 5):

`In the case of XML-based configuration metadata, you can use the init-method attribute to specify the name of the method that has a void no-argument signature`

The XML definition is an **alternative** to implementing such interfaces.

Comment: Ok...but what the framework exactlry do when I use the XML configuration? implement automatcally these interface or work in some other way?

Comment: It calls the method(s) specified in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to engage Spring's bean init / destroy

1) you can define default-init-method / default-destroy-method `beans` (root element xml config) then Spring will look for these methods in any bean it instantiates

2) you can define individual init-method / destroy-method for a bean

3) you can implement InitializingBean / DisposableBean interfaces and Spring will call them even if init-method / destroy-method are not defined in xml config

4) you can annotate methods in your bean with  @PostConstruct / @PreDestroy annotations and switch on `<context:annotation-config />` in xml config

Answer (score -2):

While today’s generation comprises of fast actions, many amongest you who do not have a strong mindset which stop you from fulfilling your dreams